# Conditionally refine database query based on non null filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 15 columns in my view page e.g. Reference name, shape, color, weight, price etc

I am getting all these to data to refine the database, if user does not select shape then it not use shape to refine, whatever user selects for refinement only those item should be in query.

My code to get data-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ParametricSearch(List<string> SourceId, List<string> ShapeId, int[] Weights, List<string> ColorId)
{
    ...some code is here....
}
```

My problem is when user not selects 'shape' then it is null and i does not want to add it in query to refine, only select items should be in query.
how can i write query to refine all database using these fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain `Where` clauses using LINQ to Entities. Something along these lines:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ParametricSearch(List<string> SourceId, List<string> ShapeId, int[] Weights, List<string> ColorId)
{
     var query = yourDataContext.YourEntityName;

     if (SourceId != null && SourceId.Count > 0)
     {
         query = query.Where(x => SourceId.Contains(x));
     }

     if (ShapeId!= null && ShapeId.Count > 0)
     {
         query = query.Where(x => ShapeId.Contains(x));
     }

     if (ColorId!= null && ColorId.Count > 0)
     {
         query = query.Where(x => ColorId.Contains(x));
     }

     var result = query.Take(50).ToList();
     return View(result);
}
```

Comment: i have 15-16 fields, then i have to check it 15-16 time it is too long. Can i write it in single query

Comment: @Satyawan, I don't see a straight forward way of doing it in a single query.

Comment: I does not want to take all record in database, i want to get only top 50 records which is refined by query

Comment: @Satyawan, that's not part of your original question. Nevertheless, I updated my answer. You can use the `Take` method to specify the number of records you want to fetch from the database.

Comment: @Satyawan, if the answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as an answer.